# How to add a click effect to a button on click event?

Tags: android, xml, state

How would I add a click effect similar to the below image for a button click event?

The button in my activity already has it's background set to an image so I'm not sure how I would add a background of a state also as in this tutorial:

[Android Button color changing on onClick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189715/android-button-color-changing-on-onclick)

[image: Button state change on press:]

Comment: use a selector for this purpose

Comment: May I know how did you style the 3rd button? It looks beautiful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two image, one for normal state and another for pressed state. At first create a selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_image" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_image"/>

</selector>
```

Add this selector in your button as a background.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [something similar](http://richardgilmour.co.uk/2012/10/28/customising-an-android-button/). I am not sure though, if this fits your solution.

EDIT: It uses selector, just like @Raghunandan suggested above.