# How to change button color

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I have few buttons.
I'd like to change color of a button when it is pressed.
And to change color of other buttons to normal state.

The problem is that after simple changing the background of a button,
it's shape is also changed. After changing the color the default android 
button with shadows
is just replaced with painted rectangle with more button height.
Yes. It is possible to define button in normal and pressed positions as drawable XMLs.
But I'd like to use default android buttons instead of fancy mine.

My code is below:

```
        buttonAny.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buttonAny.setBackgroundColor(COLOR_BUTTON_SELECTED);
            buttonMale.setBackgroundColor(COLOR_BUTTON_GRAY);
            buttonFemale.setBackgroundColor(COLOR_BUTTON_GRAY);
        }
    });

    buttonMale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buttonAny.setBackgroundColor(COLOR_BUTTON_GRAY);
            buttonMale.setBackgroundColor(COLOR_BUTTON_SELECTED);
            buttonFemale.setBackgroundColor(COLOR_BUTTON_GRAY);
        }
    });
```

XML:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGenderAny"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim1"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text='Any'
        android:textColor="@color/text1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonGenderMale"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim1"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text='Male'
        android:textColor="@color/text1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

My app after start looks as follows
[pic1](http://www.k-ct.com/temp/q1.jpg)
(Sorry I have not permission to post images)

After I press a button it is as follows:
[pic2](http://www.k-ct.com/temp/q2.jpg)

Very strange, that the size of the buttons was changed.

There are many similar questions in google.
But it seems they do not suit me.
For example [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189715/android-button-color-changing-on-onclick).
But there is not written how to define normal or pressed button in drawable.

So. What is the best way to change (switch) colors of a few buttons.
Thanks!

Comment: You have permission to post the XML layout. Post it!

Comment: Okay, I've posted ...

Comment: you are overriding the whole button settings on the onclick listener... I recomend yout to write a xml file with all the properties of the button that you want to display... and then in the onclick lisener you set it as a background resourse...

Comment: Hmm.  What I should do instead? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I am novice. And could not understand what to do.

Comment: I posted an example, the other answer took my idea!

Comment: if any of the answers gave you some help you can up vote it...

Comment: Sorry, I have no permissions to vote up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new xml file under your drawable resourses with the properties you want to apply to your button... for example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item android:state_pressed="true" >
         <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
             <corners android:radius="3dip" />
             <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#c53e2b" />
             <gradient  android:angle="-90"  android:startColor="#a11005" android:endColor="#d62608"  />            
         </shape>
     </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
         <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
             <corners android:radius="3dip" />
             <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#c53e2b" />
             <solid  android:color="#e0341e"/>       
         </shape>
     </item>  
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
             <corners android:radius="3dip" />
             <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#c53e2b" />
             <gradient  android:angle="-90"  android:startColor="#ff6c52" android:endColor="#e0341e" />            
         </shape>
     </item>
</selector>
```

then in the on click listener aplyy it like this...

```
 buttonMale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            buttonAny.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.YOUR_XML_NAME);
            buttonMale.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.YOUR_XML_NAME);
            buttonFemale.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.YOUR_XML_NAME);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You've got the right idea with the StateListDrawable defined in XML. However, it is probably not a good idea to set this in an `onClickListener`. Rather, it should be set in the layout XML.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the idea. I will try to find (or define myself) a standart (default) buttons in xml with different background colors. I hope  changing the background  will not touch the shape and size again....

Comment: @Niaz you can see a good example for a default button's background drawable in the Android platform! Hurrah for open source! https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/btn_default_holo_light.xml

Comment: Scott W, Unfortunately there are no so many btn... in my compilation for Android 1.6 in buttonAny.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn... ));  I wonder how to enter usual android button as drawable xml and then to play with background there. I hope the height of button will not changed as it was if I just change the background. As I said, I don't need fancy drawable buttons, I just need a default android button with different colors.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create an xml file in the drawable folder which will set the back ground colour of your buttons according to the states i.e pressed or not.
For example create a file and call it button_background.xml and place it in drawable folder.The in the file put the following

```
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#449def" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <solid android:color="#2f6699" />
</item>
```

Then in your button background attribute

```
<Button
   android:background="@drawable/button_background"/>
```

You can edit the colors in the button_background file to your taste.

Comment: My main problem is that after changing background of a button the shape is also changed. And I have the follows: http://www.k-ct.com/temp/q2.jpg   How to define default android button in drawable xml? I hope it will not change the shape, if I change it's background. Yes, I can enter some fancy buttons in drawable XMLs, but I'd like to use just default usual android buttons

Comment: @Niaz if you follow the above  code,it should work fine.I have edited it.Please have a look.

Comment: mungaih kamau, your code works, but unfortunately it changes the height of buttons. And I have performance like here:  http://k-ct.com/temp/q2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, don't try to change the button color in your `onClick` event.

What you are looking for is a [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList). As an example, check out how the Android platform defines the drawable [btn_default_holo_light](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/btn_default_holo_light.xml). You will want to follow exactly this pattern, providing your own drawables (e.g. PNG images) for the different states.

Once you've got these drawables created, you simply reference it in your layout file like this

```
<Button
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/my_fancy_button_background" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to change colors in the code just use a `selector` for all the buttons as the `background` property of each button.

Selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_selected="true"><color android:color="@color/button_background_pressed" />
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true"><color android:color="@color/button_background_pressed" />
</item>
<item><color android:color="@color/button_background" />
</item>

</selector>
```

**EDIT:**
You can create a `selector` with the above XML in your `drawable` folder and just use it as a `background` with `"@drawable/selector_button"`

**EDIT 2:**

Instead of using it like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonGenderMale"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim1"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text='Male'
    android:textColor="@color/text1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Use it like this:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dip"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

   <View 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip" />

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonGenderMale"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim1"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text='Male'
    android:textColor="@color/text1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Adjust the `View` for the distance you want between buttons!

Comment: It works, but the same problem. All buttons are connected with each other with no interval. As I showed in "pic2". I am curious how to define button as drawable XML exactly as default android button, so after changing the color it should have exactly the same shape and size...

Comment: Akagami, yes, it is a good idea. But after changing the color the shape of button is also changed. It became just a paint rectangle, no shadows around button

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,create a xml file int project's res/drawable,eg:"buttonGenderAny_bg.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:drawable="COLOR_BUTTON_SELECTED" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="COLOR_BUTTON_SELECTED" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="COLOR_BUTTON_SELECTED" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="COLOR_BUTTON_GRAY"/>
```

then set button's background in layout xml file,eg:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonGenderMale"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim1"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text='Male'
    android:textColor="@color/text1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonGenderAny_bg"/>
```

Comment: I have written these words in the topic start: The problem is that after simple changing the background of a button, it's shape is also changed. After changing the color the default android button with shadows is just replaced with painted rectangle with more button height. Yes. It is possible to define button in normal and pressed positions as drawable XMLs. But I'd like to use default android buttons instead of fancy mine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I also did some thing like this a few months back with buttons, but I don't recommend it. I think for your situation it is much simpler to use radio buttons.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VZZv.png) is what it looked like!

The advantage of using the RadioGroup method is that you do not have to manage the color state of your "buttons"

To setup the following 3 or 4 files are needed (This is my **EXACT** usage, but I have also provided a few hints on how to get it like how you want it):

Layout:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/sortOptionsBar"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/rbSortOption1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbSortOption1"
        style="@style/menu_buttons"
        android:text="@string/sort_option1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbSortOption2"
        style="@style/menu_buttons"
        android:text="@string/sort_option2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbSortOption3"
        style="@style/menu_buttons"
        android:text="@string/sort_option3" />
</RadioGroup>
```

**HINT:** Above I wanted mine to look like a bar, for yours switch the android:orientation="horizontal" to vertical.

values\style.xml (To bring together all the styling for the radio buttons)

```
<style name="menu_buttons" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/menu_button_text</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/menu_button_background</item>
    <item name="android:button">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1.0</item>
</style>
```

What is important to note is the android:button above, this hides the checkbox of the radiobutton
You can also remove the android:layout_weight I used this in my bar so that all the radio buttons would get equal width.
The parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless" will allow you to keep the buttons the same size.

color\menu_button_background.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_button_unselected" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_button_selected" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/menu_button_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_button_unselected" />
</selector>
```

The same can be done for the @color/menu_button_text. (For example you could invert the color of the text when it is selected)

Then to know which one is selected in the onCheckedChanged event I did this.

```
int id = sortBar.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
switch (id) {
    case R.id.rbSortOption1:
        break;
    case R.id.rbSortOption2:
        break;
    case R.id.rbSortOption3:
        break;
    }
```